# Automatically scroll down textarea JAVA (and add images to specific areas)

Tags: java, image, user-interface, scroll, textarea

(original post asked why the textarea was not showing entirely when scroll was added, answer is that due to the layout set to null bounds must be set)
The scroll thing has been solved thank you for your time,
the image thing remains as this error occurs with setIcon
[error](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/785537293351518230/786495132996206613/unknown.png)
[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty0HC.png)

(image added with this code)

```
ImageIcon sumii=new ImageIcon("sprites/summoner.png");
        ImageIcon ranii=new ImageIcon("sprites/ranger.png");
        ImageIcon warii=new ImageIcon("sprites/warrior.png");
        ImageIcon magii=new ImageIcon("sprites/mage.png");
        JLabel sumi=new JLabel(sumii,JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel rani=new JLabel(ranii,JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel wari=new JLabel(warii,JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel magi=new JLabel(magii,JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: *If i do frame.add(scroll)* - that is correct. The scroll pane needs to be added to the frame. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. So create a JFrame that displays a JScrollPane containing a JTextArea. Once you understand the basic usage you fix your real application.

Comment: @camickr the issue with scroll was that the layout was null hence i needed to setbounds, i am truly sorry for my lack of experience, i am now stuck on the image part as setIcon(); gives the following error [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/785537293351518230/786495132996206613/unknown.png)

Comment: *hence i needed to setbounds* no. The solution is to NOT use a null layout and to use layout managers. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. This is an example of why layout managers should be used.

Comment: All questions should contain a proper [mre]. Again, if your problem is with an image. Then the "MRE" should simply be a JFrame with a JLabel and your ImageIcon. Without seeing the complete code we can only guess.